# Was there a purpose to Margaret Allison Hart being introduced in Season 7?

Tags: character, ncis

I just finished Season 7 of [NCIS](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364845/) and according to the [NCIS Wiki](http://ncis.wikia.com/wiki/Margaret_Allison_Hart), Defense Attorney Margaret Allison Hart's last episode was the end of the season.

The entire season she caused trouble for Gibbs, while trying to hit on him, but yet... did she have a purpose?

The last Episode [Rule Fifty-One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1653497/?ref_=ttep_ep24) ends with him writing down a new rule about how sometimes we can be wrong, after she comes to him with evidence about him, saying something about how she won't do anything to him. This implies that he disliked her the entire time, but was wrong about it when she ended up not doing anything with the evidence she found.

To me, this character was not needed, and just an annoyance throughout the entire season, doing things that weren't legal, while at the same time preaching about legality to Gibbs, in everything he did.

My question is, is there any actual reason as to why this character was ever introduced? Does she have an affect in later seasons on Gibbs, possibly distrusting his gut on being "wrong," or was she there purely to annoy us?

Answer (score 3):

She serves multiple purposes. She is both a romantic interest of the month for Gibbs, and a romantic foil. A foil is a literary device used to make a character stand out. Her actions as a lawyer doing illegal things contrasts Gibbs cop doing occasionally illegal things. And as you point out, his new rule is his character growing in response to the foil,  he  realizes that his first instinct is wrong, occasionally.

She literally acts as the moral of never judge a book by its cover. Which Gibbs is chronically guilty of.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Does Gibbs even show interest in her?  Her being a non-redhead and all (not sure if she causes him to change his interest in hair color), but she was also a thorn in his side, and maybe he liked that also.  I also wonder if she was the one who took the report from the Mexican cop who was the one who caused Abby to undercover the truth, since Abby did say she only had 1 report, granted Ms. Hart, as well as Director Vance both had copies.  Thanks for the answer, appreciate it.

Comment: Hard to tell with Gibbs,  but he does like strong women. Also, the character may not respond like he does, but she was clearly intended to be the romance de jour. The production paired it as a will they won't they setup. Plenty of UST.

Comment: From when we are shown he has had interest in a few "Strong women" that were military related, but it's hard to know because of his ex-wives, as well as that fling in the first few seasons who drove the convertible (benz I believe).  The thing in common with these women was being a red-head, which Allison Hart is not.   It seems to be a one-sided love to me.  However, after checking the wiki it mentions Lt Colonel Hollis Mann was a blonde, which I didn't realize, and thought she was a head-head as well, so maybe his tastes are changing.  Still didn't feel a vibe from Gibbs to Allison Hart.